# 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Error in VScode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, installation

I've recently moved to VScode for my python coding purposes and after setting up the environment, I tried running a simple Hello World code to test it and I got this error,

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've restarted my Windows, uninstalled and reinstalled Python. My Python Interpreter is set to the correct PATH. But I still can't seem to get it to work.

Edit: And Python Path is in the system environment variables

Comment: Please, can you verify if you have Python path in system environment variables?

Comment: Yes. It is. I just checked it.

Comment: Try restarting vs code